# Excel - How to concatenate 2 values to make a refference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a long column of data (15000 values) that simplified looks like this:

```
A      B          C         D
1      lorem      pellen    Vestibulum   
2      epsum      tesque    pretium
3      Morbi      vel       convallis
4      fermentum  tellus    nibh
5      Interdum   molestie  Vi
..
15000
```

Then I have a second table:

```
A           B            C
TYPE        row_start    row_end
type 1      1            765
type 2      766          468
type 3      312          1789
type 4      7775         1324
type 5      756          9999
...
```

The second table has all the data; the first row has information, from which row to which row is the data relevant for a particular type. I know on which rows is the information, I just don't know how to reach the data, that is on the same rows, but different columns.

**what I know:**
I know how to use the INDIRECT() function.

**what I want:**
I want to be able to CONCATENATE 2 strings to make a reference:
Example:

```
INDIRECT(B3)                     <<-- this works of course
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B","3"))   <<-- doesn't work
INDIRECT("B"&"3")                <<-- doesn't work
```

**what I don't want** To make extra columns, which would exist only for this purpose: i.e.

```
A           B                     C               D                ...
TYPE        info1_row_start       info1_row_end   info2_row_start  ...
type 1      Sheet_2!C1            Sheet_2!C765    Sheet_2!D1       ...     
type 2      Sheet_2!C766          Sheet_2!C468    Sheet_2!D766     ...
type 3      Sheet_2!C312          Sheet_2!C1789   Sheet_2!D766     ...
type 4      Sheet_2!C7775         Sheet_2!C1324   Sheet_2!D766     ...
type 5      Sheet_2!C756          Sheet_2!C9999   Sheet_2!D766     ...
...
```

**EDIT** 
As answered by Gary's Student, the following both work.

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B","3"))
INDIRECT("B"&"3")
```

Comment: Your examples (in `what I want` work fine.  I suspect you have oversimplified.

Comment: Gary's Student suggested using nested `INDIRECT` (please check your **EDIT**), same as me. Watch out when referring to other Worksheet, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting in an answer so as to add a picture.  But your second formula also seems to work fine:

[image]

Note that with a `2` in B3, the formula returns `B` from Sheet_2!B2

Answer (score 0):

If **A1** contains "happiness" and **B3** contains "A1", then:

```
=INDIRECT(B3)
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("B" & 3))
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B", "3")))
```

will **all** return "happiness"

Answer (score 0):

I used the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet_2!","B",B3))
```

With which I am concatenating 2 strings and a row, valued in B3.

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet_2!" & INDIRECT("B" & "3"))
```

or the like.
Be careful, as

```
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Sheet_2!" & "B" & "3"))
```

may give a different result. I guess this is the key for what you need.